# Can Programmable Cell Death (PCD) be engineered in a bacterium like E. coli?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, apoptosis

I am reading a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2406/f82979a3b40e22a32c151b02465c960139c4.pdf) which says :
**Messages not received after a certain time can be considered lost, as bacteria carrying them will suicide.**
I even read some paper which says about PCD like [this](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0966842X03003354/1-s2.0-S0966842X03003354-main.pdf?_tid=37448da4-ac42-49b7-a1ac-2e5e1bd3f23a&acdnat=1527062181_c1b3e0177efad608e452750545be5351), but it just tells about a mechanism of Toxin and Anti-toxin.

My question: **is there a reference which talks about genetically modifying E. coli bacteria (i.e. introducing a plasmid in it) which will cause cell death of the bacterium after a certain time. In short, we decide the life time of a bacterium after which it just commits suicide.**